# Pointing xampp to public folder / different folder for only one project

Tags: php, apache, xampp, document-root

I use xampp and have a project where I need to point/configure the server to a different root directory (public in this case) and I do it by going to

> xampp > Apache > Config > httpd.conf

find this

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

and change it to

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public/">
```

restart the server and this works.

My problem is that all of my other projects work on the default document root setting but I need to change the document root setting every time when I work on this particular project (I repeat the above process 3-4 times a day).

Is there a way to change the root document for only one project and let the rest work on the default setting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Why can't you just go on, and just access your project like `http://example.com/project/public`?

Comment: Thank you ... because I switch between default and custom setting 3-4 times a day, sometime even more. It is frustrating doing that on a daily basis.

Comment: Is it not possible to design your project to suit the normal document root? If not, maybe create a seperate virtualhost for it. I will guide you

Comment: Virtual hosts is the way to go. Or even better, switch to docker/nginx!